# Using LINQ to SQL to update database?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

When I execute the following code I don't get any error, but it doesn't update the changes on the database either. I have 5 entries in the table user, and after executing the following code there is no user with "Active" state in the database.

Am I supposed to write the update statement myself or does it do it for me? What can be the problem here?

```
var dbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();

List<user> users = (from u in dbContext.users
                          where u.age < 30
                          select u).ToList();

users[0].state = "Active";
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

**EDIT:**

So I know what the problem is. 
I change the State on my object, and the update statement contains the state as a where clause.
So when executing the query it can't find an item that matches - it fails on `[state] = @p4`.

Why is it using all parameters in my update statement when I have a primary key?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[user]
SET [state] = @p5
WHERE ([id] = @p0) AND ([firstName] = @p1) AND ([lastName] = @p2) 
    AND ([age] = @p3) AND ([state] = @p4)
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- @p1: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [firstName     ]
-- @p2: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [lastName  ]
-- @p3: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [25]
-- @p4: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Active    ]
-- @p5: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Active]
```

Comment: That looks Ok to me, are you sure you have items that is age < 30?

Comment: yes i get back 3 items from that query

Comment: I tested your code snippet and it works for me. There is something outside of the code you have shown us that is causing the problem. Could you post a full DDL SQL?

Comment: That is not a problem.  That's called "optimistic concurrency", and what it's doing is checking to make sure the values of the table have not changed since you retrieved the object.  `@p4` contains the old value, `@p5` contains the new value.  This looks correct.  Are you certain that you are looking at the right database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the concurrency pattern on your DBML.  This website about [Updating LINQ-to-SQL entities](http://davedewinter.com/2009/04/07/linq-to-sql-updating-entities/) explains a bit about it.

Anything you *don't* want to include in the `WHERE` clause should have their `Update Check` set to `Never` on the DBML.

- Open DBML
- Select the `state` property on your `user` object
- Press F4 (to see properties)
- Change `Update Check` (the last setting in the properties) to `Never`
- Save and try again

Normally I'd turn off `Update Check` for all columns but you should do more reading to understand exactly how it works in case you need concurrency.

Comment: @aryaxt I know. `Update Check` doesn't stop the columns from being updated, it stops them from being included (i.e. checked) in the `WHERE` clause.  This answer will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem with the update statement, but it still doesn't update the database.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you don't have a primary key on the user table or you didn't specify it in your dbml file. LINQ to SQL only throws exceptions when you insert or delete a record with no primary key. It doesn't throw an exception when updating for some reason.

Comment: have you checked Primary Key property of your primary key column in your dbml designer? Is it "True"?

Comment: yes it's set to true, and the primary key icon shows up on my "id" field

Comment: Is it possible to see the sql statement that is being executed by LINQ on the database?

Comment: @aryaxt: Yes. Use `dbContext.Log = Console.Out` or set it to some other `TextWriter` of your choosing.

Comment: @evpo: This was my first thought too. I've seen this behavior before and the problem was exactly as you describe.